# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{a + b*\sqrt2\ \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is an ordered field

Tags: abstract-algebra, axioms

I am trying to prove that the set $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{a + b*\sqrt2\ \mid a,b \in  \mathbb{Q}  \}$$ is an ordered field. Proving that this is a set is easy but "order" part was a challenge for me. In the book I am reading (Introduction to Mathematical Structures by Steven Galovich), the ordered field axioms are as follows:

$(i)$ If $x$ and $y$ are in $F^+$, then $x + y$ and $x*y$ are also in $F^+$
$(ii)$ For each $x \in F$, exactly one of the following three conditions holds: $$(a)\;x \in F^+,$$ $$(b) \; x = 0,$$ $$(c) \; (-x) \in F^+ $$

I tried various criteria for $F^+$ however none of them worked. Can anyone show a suitable criteria or give an indirect proof for this set being an ordered field. (Except for the one that use "$R$ is ordered and this is a subset...", because that's beyond my current knowledge).

Comment: I think inheriting the ordering from $R$ really is your best approach. It is intuitively obvious and not that difficult to turn intuition into a formal proof, since addition and multiplication are "the same" in $Q(\sqrt{2})$ and in $R$.

Comment: Maybe this will help?  http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html1/node19.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which is an ordered field.

Comment: I abstracted so much that for the whole time I forgot that $\sqrt2$ is actually a real number and I can inherit the order from $\mathbb{R}$. My method was like proving $\mathbb{C}$ is not ordered. Thank you!